# How do I implement a click counter/scorekeeper with ONLY JS (if it is possible)?

Tags: javascript, function, canvas, numbers, click

I am trying to finish the main framework of a computer game that I am creating and am trying to implement "scores" or values into it to make it more functional.

I have some basic code that actually works, but not exactly how I want to.

Here is the code that I have been using (all the variables have been declared)

```
var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 600;
        this.canvas.height = 480;
        //this.canvas.style.cursor = "none"; //hide the original cursor
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 1);
        window.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
            myGameArea.x = e.pageX;
            myGameArea.y = e.pageY;
            console.log("hello");
        });
        window.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
            myGameArea.x = false;
            myGameArea.y = false;
        });
    }, 
    clear : function(){
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}
function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
    this.type = type;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;    
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;    
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        if (this.type == "text") {
            ctx.font = this.width + " " + this.height;
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);

        } else {
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }

    }
    this.clicked = function() {
        var myleft = this.x;
        var myright = this.x + (this.width);
        var mytop = this.y;
        var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
        var clicked = true;
        if ((mybottom < myGameArea.y) || (mytop > myGameArea.y) || (myright < myGameArea.x) || (myleft > myGameArea.x)) {
          clicked = false;
        }
        return clicked;
      }
}

function updateGameArea() {
    myGameArea.clear();
    if (myGameArea.x && myGameArea.y) {
        if (item1.clicked()) {
            console.log("red square says hi");
            myScore = myScore + 1;
        }
        if (item2.clicked()) {
            console.log("orange square says hi");
        }
        if (item3.clicked()) {
            console.log("yellow square says hi");
        }
        if (item4.clicked()) {
            console.log("green square says hi");
        }
        if (item5.clicked()) {
            console.log("blue square says hi");
        }
        if (item6.clicked()) {
            console.log("purple square says hi");
        }      
    }

    scoreDisplay.text = "Score: " + myScore;
    scoreDisplay.update();
    myGamePiece.update();
    item1.update();
    item2.update();
    item3.update();
    item4.update();
    item5.update();
    item6.update();
    itemArea.update();
    orderScreen.update();
}
```

When I click the red square(item1) the score increases, but it doesn't stop until I stop clicking or my mouse is up. I want my code to simply increase the value once per click of the object instead of increasing when the mouse is down.

Comment: You could update your clicked function to return true only when first clicked, but return false until it is released again, that way you only increment on the initial click

Comment: How would I be able to do that? Would I have to move the functions?

Answer (score 0):

The logic behind what you want to happen is pretty much this :

JavaScript :

```
var i = 0;
    function addPoint() {
        if (document.getElementById("value").value != null) {
            document.getElementById("value").value = ++i;
        } else { return false }
    }
```

HTML :

```
<button onclick="addPoint()">+1 Point</button>
<input type="text" id="value" value="0"></input>
```

If you want a more "complete" approach, you could do this on the JavaScript part :

```
function addPoint() {
    var addValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("value").value, 10);
    addValue = isNaN(addValue) ? 0 : addValue;
    addValue++;
    document.getElementById("value").value = addValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an event listener like you did for the events `mousedown`
 and `mouseup`:

> *This will capture every click inside your canvas, not outside.*

**Define a variable in your** `myGameArea` **object:**

```
var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    clicks : 0, //HERE
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 600;
        this.canvas.height = 480;
    ...
```

**And then, add the event listener on the** `start()` **function:**

```
var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    clicks : 0,
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 600;
        this.canvas.height = 480;
        //this.canvas.style.cursor = "none"; //hide the original cursor
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 1);
        window.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
            myGameArea.x = e.pageX;
            myGameArea.y = e.pageY;
            console.log("hello");
        });

        this.canvas.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{ // Use ES6 arrow function
          this.clicks++;
        });

    ...
```

**Take a look at an example:**

```js
var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.querySelector("canvas"),
    clicks : 0,
    start : function(){
       this.canvas.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{ // Use ES6 arrow function
          this.clicks++;
          console.log(`Click+1, now = ${this.clicks}`);
       });
    }
};

myGameArea.start();
```

```css
canvas{
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```